# Write breakpoints in Xdebug?

Tags: php, xdebug, breakpoints

I want to debug a PHP application, I'm looking to remove a single empty line from my HTTP response.

Is it possible to break if something is written to the response ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the very short answer that you're looking for, but:

**No**, Xdebug can't break on output **yet**.

File a ticket at https://bugs.xdebug.org?